# Проблема с компиляцией кода

Tags: c++

Этот код не работает. Не могу понять причину.

```
int n, summ1, counter, chislo;
    n = 10;
    for(counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++) {
        cout << "Введите число " << counter << ":";
        cin >> chislo;
        if chislo > 0 {
            if chislo % 2 = 0 {
                summ1 += chislo;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Сумма чисел = " << summ1 << endl;
    system("pause");
```

Comment: Чем отличается "работает" от "не работает"? ПС. В следующий раз, пожалуйста, повнимательнее с метками, это не С.

Comment: Не работает - это как работает, только наоборот.
Ну или так:
pow(работает, -1). 
Надеюсь, понятно =/

Comment: Ваш код **не компилируется**. Вы не видите разницы между *работать* и *компилироваться*? Ваш юмор, если его можно так назвать, совершенно неуместен. И вообще, вы книжки читаете? `if chislo > 0 {`, например - как *правильно* записывается конструкция `if`?

Comment: Да, тупанул. Забыл добавить скобки в условиях. исправил ошибку.
Очень удивлен такому недружелюбию. Ведь я новичок, я могу запутаться, или ошибиться.
Параллельно изучаю Питон, где нет такого напряга как в C++ и иногда путаюсь.

Comment: @РоманРатушный "Недружелюбие" (которого, вообще-то, нет) вызвано тем, что Вы вроде бы пришли за помощью, а ведете себя так, словно собрались с друзьями пивка попить. Будьте, пожалуйста, серьезнее. И почитайте вот [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int n, summ1, counter, chislo;
    n = 10;
    for(counter = 1; counter <= n; counter++) 
    {
        cout << "Введите число " << counter << ":";
        cin >> chislo;
        if (chislo > 0)
        {
            if (chislo % 2 == 0)
            {
                summ1 += chislo;
            }

        }
    }

    cout << "Сумма чисел = " << summ1 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вроде все работает. Е вас не стояли () в условии